# Animacion cuando carga pagina principal ( solo una vez ) vuejs

Tags: javascript, css3, vue.js

Tengo una animación en `css3` la cual deseo que se ejecute cuando cargue la pagina y solo se ejecute una vez el problema se encuentra cuando voy una pagina adelante y me devuelvo se reinicia la animación
o cuando entran al sitio después de  haber salido, se me ocurre hacerlo con js pero como con el `localStorage`
la pregunta es:

cual es la mejor forma para realizar esto?

Comment: Te refieres a mostrar contenido (por ejemplo un `loader`) cuando se está renderizando/cargando la aplicación en el div principal (ej. `<div id="app"></div>`)? Qué es lo que has intentado?

Comment: Lo que pasa es que quiero tener una animación al inicio, la cual ya la tengo en css3 pero dura demasiado casi 20s así que creo que seria mejor solo utilizarla una vez y esa vez pienso que debe ser la primera vez que entra a la pagina

Comment: Si usas un sistema de rutas (router), por ejemplo, vue-router, podrías utilizar una ruta para mostrar esa animación y que esa ruta solo sea visitada la primer vez que entras en la app (podrías validarlo con un clave/valor en las cookies o localStorage). Al finalizar la animación navegarías a la página principal de la app.

Comment: La sugerencia de @JoseHermosillaRodrigo es buena. 
De todas formas, ¿porque tienes una animación de 20segundos en tu app?